# Calculator using Switch in Java

Tags: java, switch-statement, calculator

I'm new to Java programming. I am trying to make a Fraction Calculator but when I try to run the program it gives me an error. The error is with the Switch statements but I don't know what happened.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to My FracCalc");
        boolean continueProcessing = true;
        while (continueProcessing) {
            System.out.println("Type an expression and press <enter>");

            String Operand1 = console.next();
            if (Operand1.equals("quit")) {
                continueProcessing = false;
                System.out.println("Good bye!");
                break;
            } else {
                Operand1 = parseFullNumber(Operand1);
            }

            String Operator = console.next();
            if (Operator.equals("quit")) {
                continueProcessing = false;
                System.out.println("Good bye!");
                break;
            } else if (Operator.equals("+") || Operator.equals("-") || Operator.equals("/") || Operator.equals("*")) {

            } else {
                throw new ArithmeticException();
            }

            String Operand2 = console.next();
            if (Operand2.equals("quit")) {
                continueProcessing = false;
                System.out.println("Good bye!");
                break;
            } else {
                Operand2 = parseFullNumber(Operand2);
            }


            System.out.println( Operand1 + " " +  Operator + " " + Operand2); 
            //System.out.println("First Fraction is: " + Operand1);
            //System.out.println("Operator is: " + Operator);
            //System.out.println("Second Fraction is: " + Operand2);


            float answer;
            System.out.println(Operator);
            switch (Operator) {
                case "+":
                    answer = Operand1 + Operand2;
                    break;

                case "-":
                    answer = Operand1 - Operand2;
                    break;

                case "*":
                    answer = Operand1 * Operand2;
                    break;

                case "/":
                    answer = Operand1 / Operand2;
                    break;

        }   
    }
}

    public static String parseFullNumber(String input) {
        int wholeNumber = 0;
        int numerator = 0;
        int denominator = 0;
        ;
        int underscoreId = input.indexOf('_');
        int slashId = input.indexOf('/');

        // Check for underscore "_" //
        if (underscoreId > -1) { 
            wholeNumber = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(0, underscoreId));
            numerator = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(underscoreId + 1, slashId));
            denominator = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(slashId + 1, input.length()));
        } else {
            if (slashId > -1) {
                // no underscore but there is a slash // 
                numerator = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(0, slashId));
                denominator = Integer.parseInt(input.substring(slashId + 1, input.length()));
            } else {
                // there is no underscore or slash // 
                wholeNumber = Integer.parseInt(input);
            }
        }

        return simplify(wholeNumber, numerator, denominator);
    }

    //simplifying fractions //
    public static String simplify(int wholeNumber, int numerator, int denominator) {
        // absolute values //
        int absNumerator = Math.abs(numerator);

        // factor if applicable //
        if (absNumerator > 1) {
            int commonFactor = 1;
            for (int i = 2; i < Math.min(absNumerator, denominator); i++) {
                if (numerator % i == 0 && denominator % i == 0) {
                    commonFactor = i;
                }
            }
            numerator /= commonFactor;
            denominator /= commonFactor;
        }

        // reduce if applicable //
        if (absNumerator > denominator) {
            int reduction = numerator / denominator;
            if (wholeNumber >= 0) {
                wholeNumber += reduction;
            } else {
                wholeNumber -= reduction;
            }
            numerator %= denominator;
        }

        // prints //
        if (wholeNumber != 0) {
            if (numerator != 0) {
                return wholeNumber + "_" + numerator + "/" + denominator; 
            } else {
                return String.valueOf(wholeNumber);
            }
        } else {
            if (numerator != 0) {
                return numerator + "/" + denominator;
            } else {
                return String.valueOf(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the error i got:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: 
     Unresolved compilation problems: 
          Type mismatch:
              cannot convert from String to float The operator - is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.String, java.lang.String
              The operator * is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.String, java.lang.String
              The operator / is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.String, java.lang.String 
                  at FracCalcApp.main(FracCalcApp.java:53)
```

Comment: There is a compile time error with the switch statements

Comment: You're missing a `}` at the end of your switch statement I think. But posting the full error verbatim is more useful.

Comment: I called the plumber the other day and said "my pipes don't work". Then I went to the mechanic and said "my car doesn't work". They both asked for more information - funny that, I thought they were mind readers!

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from String to float
 The operator - is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.String, java.lang.String
 The operator * is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.String, java.lang.String
 The operator / is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.String, java.lang.String

 at FracCalcApp.main(FracCalcApp.java:53)

Comment: added the exception to the the post for everyones benefit. Please verify

Comment: Sooner or later you're going to have to deal with operator precedence and parentheses, at which time you will have to throw much of this away and use a proper expression parser. I would do that now so you don't waste too much time going down the wrong rabbit hole. Look up the Dijkstra Shunting-yard algorithmm, or recursive descent expression parsing. Don't try to roll your own, you'll fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Operand1` and `Operand2` are `String`(s). You  need to parse them before you can perform arithmetic. Something like,

```
double answer;
System.out.println(Operator);
switch (Operator) {
case "+":
    answer = Double.valueOf(Operand1) + Double.valueOf(Operand2);
    break;
case "-":
    answer = Double.valueOf(Operand1) - Double.valueOf(Operand2);
    break;
case "*":
    answer = Double.valueOf(Operand1) * Double.valueOf(Operand2);
    break;
case "/":
    answer = Double.valueOf(Operand1) / Double.valueOf(Operand2);
    break;
}
```

Finally, by convention, Java variables should start with a lower case letter; `operand1`, `operand2` and `operator`.

Comment: Thank you this was really helpful. Also I went through my code and lower case all variables.

Comment: Another error: Type an expression and press <enter>
1_1/2 + 1_1/2
1_1/2 + 1_1/2
+
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1_1/2"
 at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
 at java.lang.Double.valueOf(Unknown Source)
 at FracCalcApp.main(FracCalcApp.java:53)

Comment: 1.5 + 1.5 also gave me an error. Also I want to retain the fractions. I'm trying to take two fractions and do operations with them. The user would input proper or improper fractions.

Comment: Editing your question to include my code isn't really cool. I suggest you consider that you haven't implemented any of those operations and you will need to do so if you want support proper or improper fractions.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter first number");
    float a = sc.nextFloat();

    System.out.println("Enter second number");
    float b = sc.nextFloat();

    System.out.println("choose your operation");
    char operator = sc.next().charAt(0);
    float answer;
    switch (operator){

        case '+' :
         answer = a +b;
            System.out.println("Answer:"+answer);
            break;
        case '-' :
            answer = a-b;
            System.out.println("Answer:"+answer);
            break;
        case '*' :
            answer = a*b;
            System.out.println("Answer:"+answer);
            break;
        default:
            answer = a/b;
            System.out.println("Answer:"+answer);
    }



  }
```